# Mixed Integer Implementation

Tags: convex-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I have a problem where I want to optimize a path while performing obstacle avoidance in a known map like the following:
[image]

Representing the hiperplanes as $h_i x\leq k_i$ but I need to put into the optimizer the valid region, but this one is non-convex and I don't know how to represent it to put it into an optimizer. In

*Prodan, Ionela; Stoican, Florian; Olaru, Sorin; Niculescu, Silviu-Iulian*, [**Mixed-integer representations in control design. Mathematical foundations and applications**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-26995-5), SpringerBriefs in Electrical and Computer Engineering. Control, Automation and Robotics. Cham: Springer (ISBN 978-3-319-26993-1/pbk; 978-3-319-26995-5/ebook). xii, 107 p. (2016). [ZBL1337.93001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1337.93001).

The authors present the following simple example, but the problem is that I do not know which value corresponds to $\alpha_i \quad \forall i$ because they work as *activators* depending on my current  but I cannot provide this condition in a NLP solver like ACADO.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-convex problem so you will likely need binary variables to model it.  In the model you are referencing in the text, the $\alpha$ variables are binary and represent the conditions that the point $x, y$ is outside the boundary defined by a side of a convex obstacle.

If a point $x, y$ is outside a set of rectangles bounded by bottom, left, top, right $(b_i, l_i, t_i, r_i)$ it must satisfy at least one of the following.
$$ y \le b_i \\
   y \ge t_i \\
   x \le l_i \\
   x \ge r_i$$

Adopting the notation in the book, we define $\alpha_{ib}, \alpha_{it}, \alpha_{il}, \alpha_{ir}$ to indicate that $x, y$ is either below, above, to the left or to the right
of object $i$.  We enforce the definition with the following constraints
$$y \le b_i + (1 - \alpha_{ib}) M \\
x \le l_i + (1 - \alpha_{il}) M \\
y \ge \alpha_{it} t_i\\
x \ge \alpha_{ir} r_i \\
\alpha_{ik} \in \{0, 1\}, \forall {k \in \{ b,l,t,r \}} $$

Where $M$ is the maximum of the upper or right coordinate ($M$ could be reduced for each rectangle and side).  These constraints work because if a given $\alpha$ is 0, the associated constraint is always satisfied and if $\alpha$ has value $1$, then it is equivalent to the conditions defining below, to the left, above or to the right.

The point is outside the rectangle if
$$\sum_{k \in \{ b,l,t,r \}} \alpha_{ik} \ge 1$$

and outside of all rectangles if the condition holds for all rectangles $i$.

One issue you now have is that binary restrictions may not be supported in ACADO, however there are many solvers that do.

Comment: Thanks @David, which software do you recommend to minimize a non-convex cost function and with constraints on kinematics (the kinematics of my vehicle are non-linear) and that deals as well with mixed integer representations for collision avoidance

Comment: Moreover, it is still not clear to me how the binary alpha’s are introduced into the solver, because they change their value depending on <x,y> so how do you introduce the changing rule into the solver?

Comment: @HectorEstebanCabezos The $\alpha$ are variables so they are expected to change when the values of $<x, y>$ change.